# ignore the headings while creating array

Tags: numpy, iopro

This code works but the only problem is that the first row is treated as heading while my csv file starts with the data.

```
import iopro

access_key='xxx'
secret_key='yyy'

my_file='employee.txt.gz'
my_folder='viva_temp'

adapter = iopro.s3_text_adapter(access_key, secret_key, my_folder, my_file,  parser='csv', delimiter = '\t', compression='gzip', header=0)
```

Even if I try to change the field names using the method, it will replace the first row with the given values.

```
adapter.field_names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Does iopro always consider the first row as heading?

Comment: Because It returns numpy array

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/: best tags also work if they were the only tag on the question. I found your question by looking up questions in the numpy tag, and it has very little to do with numpy.

Comment: Try `field_names=False`, see comments to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530708/pandas-dataframe-add-header-without-replacing-current-header

Comment: Thanks. That worked. For the sake of completeness can you post above comment as answer? field_names as an option was not mentioned when I tried help(iopro.s3_text_adapter)

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530708/pandas-dataframe-add-header-without-replacing-current-header), set `field_names = False` (verified by the OP).